# AJAX returns 404 in Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

ViewResolver (my jsp is in the right folder as specified on prefix value):

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers --> 
<!-- to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.fst</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {   
    private static final Logger logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home(String user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("Home controller has been executed");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        mv.addObject("userName", user);
        mv.addObject("controllerName", request.getRequestURI());
        mv.setViewName("home");

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testAjax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testAjax(@RequestParam("memberId") String id, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Locale locale, Model model) {

        logger.info("Text Ajax action has been executed. My Parameter is " + id);

        return id;
    }
}
```

After turning on Tomcat 8 server on STS IDE, accessing this web with this url `http://localhost:8080/home.fst` works okay.

But on the page, calling AJAX like below throws a `404` error:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/testAjax.fst",
    data: {"memberId" : "test"},
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    } 
});
```

This is console error log:

```
 POST http://localhost:8080/testAjax.fst 404 (Not Found)
 k.cors.a.crossDomain.send                     jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4
 n.extend.ajaxhome.fst:11 (anonymous function) jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
 n.event.dispatch                              jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
 r.handle
```

Strange thing is that it calls `testAjax` controller just fine and there's no error log on server.

```
logger.info("Text Ajax action has been executed. My Parameter is " + id);
```

When `textAjax` action is invoked by my AJAX, the log is printed as well. I checked it out with debug point too (it broke alright).

What seems to be the matter??

Comment: Try with only /testAjax in url

Comment: @HarshalPatil Worse than trying with `.fst`. It cannot even invoke the controller.

Comment: yes. i think you need to give root url then try again like specify project name in url then /testAjax it will work.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Neither does work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything's good just Add `@ResponseBody` annotation in your method and also I suggest you to change your request method `POST` to `GET`

**Spring**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testAjax", method = RequestMethod.GET) //Made Change
@ResponseBody //added
public String testAjax(@RequestParam("memberId") String id,     HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Text Ajax action has been executed. My Parameter is " + id);

    return id;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", //Made Change
    url:"/testAjax.fst",
    data: {"memberId" : "test"},
    success: function (result) {
    console.log(result)
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why adding `@ResponseBody` could solve this problem?

Comment: You're welcome :) . Since we want content not whole jsp file. In simple way @ResponseBody will return the content directly without any JSPs.

Comment: I think POST is possible as well and always better approach for sending Data. The main solution is the @ResponseBody.