# Rest Service not working when deployed on AWS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-restcontroller

This is my Rest Service.

```
@RestController
public class ProjectController {    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getProjects")
    public ArrayList<Project> getProjects() {
        ArrayList<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<Project>();
        ProjectDao obj = new ProjectDao();
        projectList = obj.getProjects();
        return projectList;
    }
}
```

And this is my Angular script to invoke this service.

```js
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/getProjects"
})
.then(
    function success(response) {
        ...
    },
    function error {
        alert("Error");
    }
);
```

These are working fine when I run the application on my localhost. But, it fails when I deploy my spring-boot application on AWS and run it on server. Server returns **HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available** instead of JSON data when I enter the URL of the service in browser. What's the problem here?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869849/ajax-returns-404-in-spring-mvc

Comment: How are you serving your Angular app? Because you use / here, if you are hosting from a different location that your Spring Boot app is, then the 404 would make sense. In that case also @Keval's point about Cross Origin Request would also be correct.


Also remember that Spring Boot apps run on 8080, but If you're visiting http://SOME_IP_ON_AWS:8080/ then that's the simplest thing possible. Beyond that, are there load balancers in the way, or using Apache or Nginx to proxy requests ad that's set up wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mkyong solved it.

[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/) is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

add `@CrossOrigin` annotation with `@RestController`